# Facebook login prompt not auto disappear after user login in Kik Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I call

```
FB.login(function(response) {
            loginButtonClicked = false;
            if (response) console.log("here");
 }, {
            scope: "friends_relationships, manage_notifications, read_friendlists, user_hometown"
})
```

A login prompt should appear and after the user submit the account information the login should auto disappear and at the same time the callback function in FB.login should be called.

This works as expect in most browsers but not in Kik Messenger. When I test it in Kik Messenger, it does direct me to a webpage to login, however the window doesn't get disappeared after I submit the information and the callback function in FB.login() never gets called.

I have no idea why this happens and how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook SDK only support browsers. Kik Messenger uses WebView which is not supported by Facebook SDK.